# How do I clone and append anchor html value of <a href="#">Barbara is so nice</a> to a div container

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

How do I clone and append anchor html value of a list with multiple `<a href="#">Barbara is so nice</a>` elements to a div container. I am able to clone the `.counter` element and append it to the container but wont work with a anchor.

I created a [jsFidle here](http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/h3Y8a/)

Here is my js code:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.ordered-list li a').on("click", function() {
        var button = $(this);
        $('.overlay').fadeIn('slow',function(){
            button.find('.user-comment-list').clone().fadeIn(1000).appendTo('.overlay-content-inner');
            button.find('.counter').clone().appendTo('.overlay-title-content');
    });
});
    $('.icon-remove').click(function(){
        $('.overlay').fadeOut('slow');
        $('.overlay-content-inner, .overlay-title-content').empty();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's a shitload of HTML in that fiddle, it would be easier if you narrowed it down to just the relevant parts.

Comment: The fiddle was quite large alright but the answer was right here, assuming my guess was correct. If you want the HTML value of the anchor use `button.html()`. `var button = $(this);` is not a button, you are binding the click event to `..li a`, hence the anchor. The reason `.content` works is because it is a child of the anchor. See my answer for the details, the fix and the DEMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you can't get the anchor value out. You are already in the anchor.

```
$('.ordered-list li a').on("click", function() {
```

You are binding the click event to the anchor. It only adds to the confusion that you name the local variable referencing the current anchor `button`.

Instead of:

```
button.find('.counter').clone().appendTo('.overlay-title-content');
```

You can do the following if you want to append the anchor HTML instead:

```
$('.overlay-title-content').append(button.html());
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h3Y8a/1/) - Appending the anchor HTML value

In case the link to the DEMO goes stale, here is the new code:

```
$('.ordered-list li a').on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this); // not a button! "this" is referencing the clicked anchor.
    $('.overlay').fadeIn('slow', function() {
        button.find('.user-comment-list').clone().fadeIn(1000).appendTo('.overlay-content-inner');
        $('.overlay-title-content').append(button.html());
        //button.find('.counter').clone().appendTo('.overlay-title-content');
    });
});
$('.icon-remove').click(function() {
    $('.overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    $('.overlay-content-inner, .overlay-title-content').empty();
});​
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make totally sense, thank you for Francois for sharing cool stuff.